# iterate through object calculate total number value in nested object

Tags: javascript, foreach, javascript-objects, nested-object

I want to iterate through the objects and calculate a total sum of all the values that appear to be in a nested object. I don't appear to be able to get the number value on its own.

```
const drunks = {
  'Cheryl': { numberOfDrinks: 10 },
  'Jeremy': { numberOfDrinks: 4 },
  'Gordon': { numberOfDrinks: 2 },
  'Laura': { numberOfDrinks: 6 }
}

let totalDrunks = 0
let numberOfDrunks = Object.values(drunks)

numberOfDrunks.forEach((drink) => {
totalDrunks += drunks[drink];
})
console.log (totalDrunks) //Expecting a number value of 22
```

Comment: Replace:
totalDrunks += drunks[drink];  
To
totalDrunks += drink.numberOfDrinks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to loop through objects. I prefer not to convert to an array just iterate using `for in` instead.

So here I'm loop through the object and then getting `numberOfDrinks` on each element.

```js
const drunks = {
  'Cheryl': { numberOfDrinks: 10 },
  'Jeremy': { numberOfDrinks: 4 },
  'Gordon': { numberOfDrinks: 2 },
  'Laura': { numberOfDrinks: 6 }
}

let totalDrunks = 0

for(let drink in drunks){
  totalDrunks+= drunks[drink].numberOfDrinks;
}

console.log(totalDrunks)
```

Comment: Make sure you declare `drink` properly in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Replace line:

```
totalDrunks += drunks[drink];
```

To

```
totalDrunks += drink.numberOfDrinks;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you are using `Object.values(drunks)`, you are getting an array of objects as a result. In your `forEach` loop, `drink` will represent each object from the array, not the actual number value of `numberOfDrinks`.

To fix this, you need to access the `numberOfDrinks` property of each object in the loop and add it to the `totalDrunks` variable. Here's the corrected code:

```js
const drunks = {
  'Cheryl': { numberOfDrinks: 10 },
  'Jeremy': { numberOfDrinks: 4 },
  'Gordon': { numberOfDrinks: 2 },
  'Laura': { numberOfDrinks: 6 }
}

let totalDrunks = 0;
let numberOfDrunks = Object.values(drunks);

numberOfDrunks.forEach((drink) => {
  totalDrunks += drink.numberOfDrinks; // Access the numberOfDrinks property of each object
});

console.log(totalDrunks); // Output: 22
```

Now, the `totalDrunks` variable will correctly hold the total sum of the `numberOfDrinks` property from each object in the `drunks` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a more functional approach you could also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const drinks = {
  'Cheryl': { numberOfDrinks: 10 },
  'Jeremy': { numberOfDrinks: 4 },
  'Gordon': { numberOfDrinks: 2 },
  'Laura': { numberOfDrinks: 6 }
}

const totalDrinks = Object.values(drinks)
  .reduce((total, person) => total += person.numberOfDrinks, 0);

console.log(totalDrinks)
```